HyperV host - Provide VM to normal user with vmconnect.exe /user /pass service account
I have a Hyper-V host with many virtual machines, and I want to allow users to access these VMs using the vmconnect.exe tool.
However, I don't want to grant normal users access to the Hyper-V Manager or the management tools.
My plan is to use vmconnect.exe and provide credentials for a service account that will enable access to all the VMs on the host.
What specific permissions or rights should this service account have to allow this level of access?
